# Is there a way access the "\" directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I've asked this question before but worded it weirdly. So, I'm asking it again.

I've seen the C:\ drive in Windows be described as `\Devices\Harddiskvolume1\`.
Is there a way to access the `\` directory?

Even if nothing important is there, would it be possible using other software?
I've heard so, but I am unable to find the answer. If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

(I have also seen it done as `\\.\GLOBALROOT`)

Not that there's any point in accessing it, just curious.

P.S. if i'm doing something wrong on this website, im new to asking questions here.

Comment: I doubt it, you are trying to access the filesystem, so it has to be a drive.  Its not like linux.

Comment: `worded it weirdly. So, I'm asking it again.` ... edit the first question, instead of posting the same question twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the real Windows root directory? Is there a tool for viewing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1764379/what-is-the-real-windows-root-directory-is-there-a-tool-for-viewing-it).  Instead of asking a new question, that is essentially the same question, you need to edit your original question so it can be reopened.

Comment: It is as if you are comparing this to the linux "root" which windows has no concept of.

Comment: The "C:\" directory IS the "\" directory. It's the root directory of the filesystem in the volume designated with the letter C. As far as the "\Devices ..." stuff, those are not actual directories, it's just part of the object namespace hierarchy created by the Windows Object Manager. The software WinObj  from Microsoft/Sysinternals will display that object directory-tree-like structure very nicely.

Comment: @kreemoweet Thank you! I'll see if that works. I'd mark this as correct if it wasn't a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kreemoweet has given an answer in the comments, so I'm just adding it to the answers list here :)

> As far as the "`\Devices ...`" stuff, those are not actual directories, it's just part of the object namespace hierarchy created by the Windows Object Manager. The software [WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) from Microsoft/Sysinternals will display that object directory-tree-like structure very nicely.

Comment: Keep in mind there are multiple different "hierarchies" in Windows (Win32 filesystem hierarchy, NT device hierarchy, etc), and the \ that corresponds to C:\ is not the same \ that corresponds to \\.\GLOBALROOT, so kreemoweet's comment about C:\ being the \ is both correct and not; it is _a_ \ but it is not _the_ \ that you were asking for (you were asking about the WinObj thing more or less).

Comment: you are right. currently editing the answer now, winobj is what i needed